# Python2.7: How to create bar graph using index and column information?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I have just started learning Python 2.7 for data science and encounter a difficulty which I could not solve after googling... I would appreciate if you could help me how to create a bar graph.

So I have a data frame like this.
[image: dataframe I have]
I created this data frame from original data using the pivot table, allocating popular activities as an index and countries in column. The data inside is a total # of votes for popular activity in each country.
From this I would like to make bar graphs based on each country. It could look  like something like this.
[image: this is a graph I want]

I would appreciate if anyone could give me some tips to make this kind of graph? I could not figure out how I allocate index on y axis and frequency in x axis.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.barh()
#pandas version bellow 0.17.0
#df.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: You can also call `df.plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @Robbie Jones - thank you for sugguestion, I add it to answer.

Comment: @jezrael  Thank you! If I wanted to create this graph with only one country(like belize example shown above), what should I do? I thought I should specify column in the dataset. So I tried:   df['belize'].plot.barh()     , but it did not work... Could I have some tips?

Comment: @Robbie Jones Thank you for your advice!

Comment: You can use double [] - `df[['belize']].plot.barh()`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the reply! I tried it and got an error message like this.. KeyError: "['belize'] not in index"    Do you know what is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe some space in column names. Check `print df.columns`. If yes, use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`